# Is there something like Regular Expressions, but for matching JSON instead of strings?

Tags: regex, json, parsing

Regular expressions allow us to specify some format a string should match, and then test to see if a string matches, find out where it matches, and capture backreferences.

I'd like to have something like this for JSON. Consider:

```
{ "title": "My blog entry",
  "author": { "name": "Joe", "id": 4324132 },
  "comments: [
    "first!!!",
    "Very insightful!",
    "A++ would read again"
  ]
}
```

You could match this with something like:

```
{ "title": (title),
  "author": *,
  "comments": [
    "first!!!",
    ...
  ]
}
```

(Which would return successful, and bind the capture `title` to the value `"My blog entry"`)

That's just an example. Would be useful for everything from validating API responses to extracting information from JSON to even (a la RE substitution) transforming JSON.

Anyone seen anything like this? Surprisingly, searching for regexes and JSON in the same context only leads to people trying to parse JSON with regexes. Ew.

Comment: You might be able to use JSONPath (http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) to do what you want, but it's not exactly a regex engine.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for an 'external' domain-specific language (DSL) for validating/consuming JSON.  I've not seen anything like it, but if you have experience with or want to learn lexing/parsing/ANTLR/etc you might be able to invent your own DSL for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few tools that could help you do this, although not exactly with regex's.

First it seems that what you need is validating your data, for that you can use [JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org/).

Second, to extract the title, assuming you don't want to decode the json string, you can either use [JSONPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) if you are in JS or PHP, or you could try [JsonGrep](http://blogs.fluidinfo.com/terry/2010/11/25/jsongrep-py-python-for-extracting-pieces-of-json-objects/) for CLI or Python. There is also [jshon](http://kmkeen.com/jshon/) for CLI parsing.

Comment: I'm not asking "can I achieve similar functionality by cobbling together disparate pieces of code?" - of *course* there are ways to validate and access JSON, it's only one of the most popular data exchange formats on the web. Responding to this with something like jshon is like responding to someone looking for RegExps by telling them MS Word has a search-and-replace function. :-)

Comment: Fair enough, but assuming you already know about those libs/tools, then I'm afraid the answer to your question is No :)

Comment: Fair enough. Time to get hacking! I partially just wanted to make sure I wasn't reinventing the wheel - or at least that I was building a useful variant of the wheel, I guess.

Comment: Another one I forgot to mention is [JSON Select](http://jsonselect.org/) - more of the same I suppose though, but might be something interesting to look at still.

Comment: Also [jgrep](http://www.devco.net/archives/2011/07/29/rich-data-on-the-cli.php) which is written in Ruby, but it's again not really a regex-like interface. I find your idea interesting, so please do publish it if you do it.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [json:select](http://jsonselect.org/#overview) - it's like CSS-selectors for JSON ... which is as close to a "regex" as you get for dealing with structured data.

If you want to play with it from the command-line, check out [underscore-cli](https://github.com/ddopson/underscore-cli), which exposes "select" as one of its commands.

Answer (score 0):

[jsonmatch](https://github.com/percolate/jsonmatch) is a library that does the validation part of what you're looking for. It's a bit simpler/lighter-weight than the JSON Schema library referenced in the accepted answer above. If you'd like to extend it to do capturing, pull requests are warmly welcomed ;).